# R partial string matching ignore spaces omni-directional

Tags: r, string, pattern-matching, string-matching

I am having issue with partial string matching. I have pairs of people, and I need to compare their names. To do this I have run a charmatch both directions on the two last names, to see if name1 is part of name2, and vice versa. I have a small dataset below to demonstrate the question. I use charmatch below; I have used pmatch as well and it returns the same result.

When charmatch says *seeks matches for the seeks matches for the elements of its first argument among those of its second...* I take that to mean it will treat each group of characters in element1  as a pattern n see if same group exists in element2. But that's obviously not what's happening, it looks like it's direction specific.

So...is it direction specific? And if so...what else can I use to do what I am describing? My EG names pun intended, what I actually run into are lots of last names where husband has his name and wife has hers + husband. I need to be able to see if husband last name exists within wife last name.

I know it can be done with regular expressions but I am not familiar with them, probably should be, but am not, so I'd prefer an answer that does not use regex.

```
eg_data <- data.frame(name1 = c('Jimmy Conway', 'Jimmy'), 
name2 = c('Conway','Jimmy Conway'))

eg_data$share_name1 <- mapply(charmatch, eg_data$name1, eg_data$name2)
eg_data$share_name2 <- mapply(charmatch, eg_data$name2, eg_data$name1)
eg_data$share_name <- 0
eg_data$share_name [(eg_data$share_name1==1 | eg_data$share_name2==1)] 
<- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Same two lines, only string detect, not charmatch.

```
eg_data$share_name1 <- mapply(str_detect,eg_data$name1, eg_data$name2)
eg_data$share_name2 <- mapply(str_detect,eg_data$name2, eg_data$name1)
```

OR even

```
eg_data$share_name1 <- ifelse(mapply(str_detect,eg_data$name1, eg_data$name2)==TRUE,1,0)
eg_data$share_name2 <- ifelse(mapply(str_detect,eg_data$name2, eg_data$name1)==TRUE,1,0)
```

Thanks for anyone who looked. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful

```
> with(eg_data, intersect(name1, name2))
[1] "Jimmy Conway"
```